Repair this stool leg

Pushing it back on after applying wood glue didn’t work

How thick is the seat, and is that wood or MDF?

The seat is 8 1/2” top of stool is jute and the legs are wood

The seat top is jute covering something—what is that something?

I’m not sure.  From the bottom it looks like particle board but when I knock on it it’s not hollow so the particle board is covering  something but I can’t know what without destroying the stool. Sorry I’m trying to learn new to DIY

For good glue holding, you want clean surfaces.  So sanding/scraping all old glue is needed.
Those screws/nails will need removing to clean the surfaces enough, either by cutting or grinding.
I assume the top surface is covered, so new screws will probably be needed to go from the leg into the base.
The base is probably at least 1/2 inch thick, so at an angle, you will have between 5/8 to 3/4 inch to drive the screws into the base without having the pointy ends sticking into you.
Use pilot holes at about a 20 to 30 degree angle into the leg for the screws.

Try inserting a dowel into the leg and making a matching hole in the base so as to make some kind of joint. Hopefully the angled screws will help - but the original construction was rather weak.

Reengineer this bad design.

With a thin pry bar carefully remove all the legs.  Sand down the bottom of the stool and the tops of the legs so they are smooth.
Cut a piece of 3/4 inch plywood or similar in a circle to fit exactly within the opening in the upholstry.
Screw the legs to the plywood using three screws per leg, from the top of the plywood.  For each leg, drill three, 3/16" holes through the plywood at the same angle as the leg.  These holes will allow a #10 screw to just pass through without turning.  Use those holes as a guide to drill three 1/8" holes in the leg.  Glue and screw each leg to the plywood using three #10 x 2" screws from above.  Countersink the top of the plywood and tighten the screws firmly.
Glue and screw the plywood to the bottom of the upholstered stool from beneath.  Experiment to see what kind of screw is appropriate for the bottom of the stool.  Glue might be enough if the two surfaces mate well.
If you want, cover the repair with fabric: black or a color matching the upholstery.  The fabric should cover the outside edges of the plywood.

